# How to use mariadb instead of sqlplus using sqlnet configuration files

Tags: oracle, mariadb, sqlplus, network, sqlnet

currently I can access a database on a remote server using
Oracle's instant client "sqlplus"

The connection is dependent on a couple of configuration files in:
$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
which are called sqlnet.ora and ldap.ora

The ldap.ora file has contents of:

```
DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT="<an ldap path>"
DIRECTORY_SERVERS=(<host1>:<port1>,<host2>:<port2>)
DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE=OID
```

the sqlnet.ora file has entries of:

```
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN=<same path as ldap path above but as a url>
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH=(LDAP, TNSNAMES)
```

I would like to be able to connect with mariadb client instead of Oracle's client, but I don't know how to configure this.

Could someone help me please?

Comment: You cannot connect with the MariaDB client to an Oracle database.

Comment: That is sad news. Are there any opensource clients that can connect to an oracle database?

Comment: Also, your down-mark is because you don't like Oracle, opensource DBs, you consider that not knowing for a fact that the two cannot connect is obvious or something else in the construct of my question?

Comment: Oracle SQLDeveloper connects to Oracle just fine. And it is free.

Comment: dbeaver (https://dbeaver.io/) and squirrel (http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) are two examples, but there's plenty more to choose from. Try googling for sql-client

Answer (score 0):

You can use heterogeneous services to connect from Oracle to other RDBMS's. You can use this to replicate data between Oracle and other database engines. You can also connect to an Oracle database using ODBC. MariaDB should be able to connect to an Oracle database with an ODBC configuration. In that case you are not using the Oracle client.

However, if you want to just manage an Oracle database you should either go the SQL Developer, PL/SQL Developer, Toad route, or just use sqlplus.

Comment: actually, with ODBC, you _are_ using the oracle client.  ODBC always requires a db-specific driver that provides a generic interface on top of the db-specific client connectivity.  Don't confuse the human-facing app (sqlplus, sql dev, toad, squirrel, etc) with the 'client software'.